# How to stay on current page after reloading using angularjs ui bootstrap pagination?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Below is my code for a simple pagination using angularjs-ui-bootstrap. Since I'll be working with too large of a data set to have it page client side I'm just grabbing the data per page when the page is changed.

The problem I'm running into is when the page is reloaded the pagination is always reset to the first page. How can I have it stay on the current page when the page is reloaded?

html

```
<uib-pagination total-items="totalCount" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="2"></uib-pagination>
```

javascript

```
    $scope.currentPage = $location.search().page;

    getData($scope.currentPage);

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        getData($scope.currentPage);
        $location.url('?page=' + $scope.currentPage);
    };

    function getData(pageNumber) {        
        if (pageNumber == null)
            pageNumber = 1;
        $http.get('http://localhost.angulartestapi.com/v1/AngularTestApi/getteams?pageNumber=' + pageNumber)
        .success(function (data) {
                $scope.teams = data.Teams;
                $scope.totalCount = data.TotalCount;
            }).error(function () {
            alert("error");
        });
```

This code currently adds a `?page={currentPage}` parameter to the url. When the page reloads it gets the saved page from `$location.search().page` goes into `getData()` with `$scope.currentPage` set to the correct page number. But then it goes into `pageChanged()` with `$scope.currentPage` reset back to `1`.

**EDIT:** Cookie approach

So I tried to save the currentPage in a cookie like this:

```
    $scope.currentPage = $cookies.get('page');

    getData($scope.currentPage);

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        getData($scope.currentPage);
        $cookies.put('page', $scope.currentPage);
    };
```

When the page reloads it gets the saved page from the cookie goes into `getData()` with `$scope.currentPage` set to the correct page number. But then it goes into `pageChanged()` with `$scope.currentPage` reset back to `1`. So the problem still happens.

**EDIT 2:**

Even when `$scope.currentPage` is hard coded to `2` when the page is reloaded `$scope.currentPage` is reset to `1` in `$scope.pageChanged`.

```
    $scope.currentPage = 2;

    getData($scope.currentPage);

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        getData($scope.currentPage);            
    };
```

**FINAL EDIT:**

Found a way to stay on the current page. Answer is below.

Comment: By `refresh` do you mean a reload? The angular model will be reinitialized on a page reload.

Comment: @NarainMittal Yeah when the page is reloaded. Is there a way to reload and stay on the current page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a way to stay on the current page after the page is reloaded:

html

```
<uib-pagination total-items="totalCount" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="2"></uib-pagination>
```

javascript

```
    $scope.savedCurrentPage = $location.search().page;        
    $scope.currentPage = $scope.savedCurrentPage;

    if ($scope.currentPage == 1) {
        getData($scope.currentPage);
        $scope.savedCurrentPage = null;
    } 

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        //Since $scope.currentPage gets reset to 1 here, check if there is a savedCurrentPage.
        if ($scope.savedCurrentPage != null) {
            $scope.currentPage = $scope.savedCurrentPage;
            //Set it to null so it only happens when the page first loads.
            $scope.savedCurrentPage = null;
        }

        getData($scope.currentPage);
        $location.url('?page=' + $scope.currentPage);                
    };

    function getData(pageNumber) {        
        if (pageNumber == null)
            pageNumber = 1;
        $http.get('http://localhost.angulartestapi.com/v1/AngularTestApi/getteams?pageNumber=' + pageNumber)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.teams = data.Teams;
            $scope.totalCount = data.TotalCount;
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert("error");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the localStorage in browser to save the current page and get that current page later when you need.

```
$scope.currentPage = 1;
localStorage.StoreCurrentPage = $scope.currentPage; 
if(localStorage.StoreCurrentPage){
    $scope.currentPage = localStorage.StoreCurrentPage;
}else{
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reload your site, angular will reload too and loose your scope/context. I think you'll have to set a cookie with ur current page and check for one every time the app loads. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: I tried saving the currentPage in a cookie but it still resets the currentPage to 1 in `$scope.pageChanged()`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use $location.search?

```
  $scope.defaultPage = 4;
  $scope.currentPage = $location.search().page || $scope.defaultPage;
  $location.url('/').search({page: $scope.currentPage});
```

I would change the code to:

```
$scope.defaultPage = 0;
$scope.currentPage = $location.search().page || $scope.defaultPage
$location.url('/').search({page: $scope.currentPage})

$scope.pageChanged = function () {
    getData($scope.currentPage + 1);
    $location.search({page: $scope.currentPage + 1});
};
```

Comment: I don't have a problem getting the correct saved currentPage from the url. It's once the page is reloaded it goes into `$scope.pageChanged()` with `$scope.currentPage` reset to `1` no matter what it was set to prior.

Comment: I just updated with how I would change the code. This should evaluate the URL first when deciding on the value of $scope.currentPage. It works on my local system, but plunker was being funky with the test.

Comment: I am using a similar functionality at work, albeit with ng-route, the concept is the same. The view data / config loads via ID, and if you reload, you stay on that view.

Comment: But when you change pages that will never save the new page you're on into the url.

Comment: If it's always grabbing the page from the url when a pageChange is fired it prevents changing pages all together.

Comment: I don't understand what I am missing. Unfortunately plunker and jsfiddle both do not work with this nicely, however running it locally, everything works for me. If I navigation with no page=, it is set to the default. If I set it to something else and reload, the value remains. You can then initialize with that value.

Comment: Yes but when you try and click on another page number or next page it won't change pages because it is always getting the currentPage from the url which is always the same. I provided an answer if you're curious as to how I solved it.

Comment: Updated again, that should set the initial page on reload, and then keep updating the parameter during paging operations.

Comment: Seems like using $routeParams or in the case of ui-router $stateParams would simplify this some so you don't need to use $location.search directly and each time you click it can just "change states" (reload the same one with new parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Short version here;

```
if(page != null){
        sessionStorage.page = page;
     }
```

here is my frontend-controller.js for details;

```
https://gist.github.com/umutyerebakmaz/722949980043d26e35d2166857877641
```